# Make one last change to NSDocument before app terminates/window closes?

Tags: cocoa, nstextfield, nsdocument, nsapplication, nsapplication-delegate

I have a basic NSDocument-based app. I need to make one last change to the document when:

1. The user closes the document's window
2. The user terminates the app

**Why?**

The document window contains an NSTextField. Usually text entered into this text field is committed to the document's model after the user presses Enter (via `textDidEndEditing(_:)`).

Let's assume the user typed some text, but does not press Enter. Instead he presses Cmd-W or Cmd-Q to close the document window or terminate the app altogether.

`textDidEndEditing` is not called so I check if the text field contains changes and try to update the document myself.

❌ Here is where it gets tricky. The following results in a deadlock on `NSDocument.performActivityWithSynchonousWaiting`:

```
override func viewWillDisappear() {
    super.viewWillDisappear()

    undoManager?.disableUndoRegistration()
    textField.commitEditing() // Updates the model

    document.updateChangeCount(.changeDone)
}
```

I managed to work around the deadlock by not hooking into `viewWillDisappear`, but into `NSDocument.canClose(withDelegate delegate: Any, shouldClose shouldCloseSelector: Selector?, contextInfo: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?)`.

✅ This code causes the changes to be saved when the user closes the document window:

```
override func canClose(withDelegate delegate: Any, shouldClose shouldCloseSelector: Selector?, contextInfo: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {

    undoManager?.disableUndoRegistration()
    textField.commitEditing() // Updates the model

    updateChangeCount(.changeDone)

    super.canClose(withDelegate: delegate, shouldClose: shouldCloseSelector, contextInfo: contextInfo)
}
```

.

❓Unfortunately, the above is not called when the user terminates the app. I tried updating my document in `applicationWillTerminate()` -- did not work. I also tried overriding `applicationShouldTerminate()` and delaying termination for 3 seconds. I can see the document's window being marked as "edited", but changes are not saved.

How can I make a last change to NSDocument right before the app terminates and have it saved automatically?

Comment: How does the user terminate the app?

Comment: Cmd-Q or via the menu bar (so a regular close, all the delegate methods of NSApplicationDelegate get called, only the document is not saved anymore at this point).

Comment: Does NSProcessInfo - (void) disableSuddenTermination help?
According to the document, <br/>
- Some AppKit functionality automatically disables sudden termination on a temporary basis to ensure data integrity.
- NSDocument temporarily disables sudden termination to prevent process killing between the time at which the user has made a change to a document and the time at which the user's change has been written to disk.

Comment: My app terminates regularly. I'm not terminating/force quitting it. I suspect that the app might be in a different runloop state when I delay termination that prevents the document from saving one last time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For reference: I don't think it is possible to make a last change to `NSDocument` while the app is being terminated. The document architecture is simply not designed that way (see https://www.mail-archive.com/cocoa-dev@lists.apple.com/msg107739.html)

At the time the app is terminating, the document's windows have been closed and window controllers released.

I eventually solved this problem by changing the design of my app to record changes to the document as the user types. I use a new instance of `UndoManager` and manually call `NSDocument.updateChangeCount(.changeDone)` to register my changes out of the undo/redo chain. When the user finally commits changes by pressing Enter, I use the document's undo manager to register the change.